# Нужно, чтобы при каждом обращении был новый ip

Tags: ip, синтаксический-анализ

Здравствуйте!

Не силен в web-програмировании, но попытаюсь описать сложившуюся ситуацию.

Имеется сайт, с которого нужно брать информацию (делать выгрузку), для чего был сделан другой сайт, который производит эту выгрузку автоматически (парсит). Все работало отлично до недавних пор, пока владелец первого сайта не установил анти ддос. В итоге мой сайт попадает в бан через пару минут.
Пробовал наладить работу через прокси - не помогает. 
Нужно, чтобы при каждом обращении был новый ip. Как это можно решить?

Comment: @zabil-007, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Я год назад столкнулся с данной проблемой. В итоге купил прокси тут http://buy.fineproxy.org/
Стоит $20 на месяц.
Скажу сразу, из того списка, что тебе будут давать, процентов 50% будут забаненых или не работать! Для этих целей тебе необходимо реализовать функцию для проверки прокси на работоспособность.
Сценарий следующий:

1. Выбираем прокси
2. Проверяем его на работоспособность
3. Если работает, то переходим на нужный нам сайт и прасим инфу. А если не работает, то возвращаемся на 1-й пункт.

Сейчас я отказался от этой идеи и покупаю индивидуальное прокси, 500 руб/шт. Дорого, но зато оно того стоит!

Comment: А индивидуальные прокси где покупаете?

Comment: Хотя впринципе такая цена везде. Ну где то на 50 рубле

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить другой IP, необходимо использовать как раз прокси сервера.
Может, стоит увеличить задержку между запросами и вообще сделать её случайной, напр., от 2 до 5 минут, чтобы сервер не считал вас за робота и не блочил IP.

Comment: В том то и дело, что задержка между запросами нужна короткая.

Comment: @zabil-007, тогда только вариант с прокси сервером, больше никак...